# How to scroll to a div within a fixed div using jQuery scrollTo

Tags: jquery, fixed, scrollto

I have 5 boxes stacked on top of each other inside of a **fixed** container `div` that is positioned `top: 40px` and `bottom: 0`, making its own container separate from other `div`s on the page.  When I click on a link with the `href="#box3"` I want the fixed container to scroll to the `div` with the `id "box3"`.  However, when I click it, nothing happens.

I'm using the "scrollTo" plugin by [Ariel Flesler](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

When I change the container `div` to `position: relative`, it works. You can view the problem here: http://shortithemes.com/demo/

Is there a solution here?

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your non-working html/javascript code? This would help you get better answers to your question.

Comment: Sure Mark, good suggestion, I have updated the post with a link: http://shortithemes.com/demo/